# Ельма, тольма, кольма

Tags: этимология

Старославянские слова *ельма, тольма* и *кольма* ранее представляли собой нечто вроде нынешних вопросительных и указательных местоимений *сколько* и *столько*, однако стоящих при этом в каких-то иных, непонятных мне доселе падежных формах (поскольку наравне с ними существовали также и такие словоформы, как *колико, толико* и *елико*, напрямую связанные с имеющимися в настоящий момент в русском языке формами). При этом ответами на данные вопросительные местоимения являлись такие числительные, как *трема, четырма, пятьма, десятьма, сотьма*, либо же такие существительные, как *дельма, польма, вельма*.

Вопрос: можно ли утверждать, что этимологическим корнем русского слова *тьма* является единственная буква "т", тогда как всё остальное, по-видимому, относится к падежному окончанию (-ьма)?

Answer (score 1):

Старославянские ельма,тольма и кольма - местоимённые наречия, как и весьма.

> Весьма́. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. Производное с помощью наречного суф.
>   -ма (ср. др.-рус. кольма, радьма и др.) от весь. Первоначальное значение — «совсем», затем — «очень».

https://lexicography.online/etymology/shansky/%D0%B2/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0

Как видим, -ма здесь наречный суффикс, зачем же сопоставлять наречие с существительным? Тьма (в значении "множество")- счётное существительное. Этимология по Фасмеру:

> Др.-русск., ст.-слав. тьма μυριάς словен. tǝmà «множество»,
>   др.-польск. ćmа «десять тысяч». **Считается калькой тюрк. tuman**
>   «десять тысяч, мгла», которое объясняли частично из авест. dunman-
>   «туман» (Шёльд, Lw. St. 37 и сл.; Гуйер, LF 52, 310), частично — из
>   тохар. tumane, tumāṃ «десять тысяч» (Мейе, IJb. I, 19); см. Мi. ЕW
>   349; Ашбот, KSz 13, 329 и сл.; Мейе, ВSL 23, 2, 114; Френкель, IF 50,
>   98; Брюкнер 66 [См. еще Вернадский, Fоr R. Jakobson, стр. 589 и сл. —
>   Т.]

Шанский поддерживает:

> ТЬМА. Общеслав. Того же корня, что латышск. tima «темнота», др.-инд.
>   támas «мрак», др.-в.-нем. dëmar «сумерки» и т. д.

Цыганенко утверждает, что тьма (множество) в др.-р. счёте - десять тысяч,

> это древнее славянское заимствование из восточных языков, возможно, из
>   монгольского (10 тысяч), в турецком - 100 тысяч. На славянской почве
>   гласный ű после полумягкого t дал ь. У славян тьма "10 тысяч" сближено
>   с сущ. тьма (мрак): великое множество, неисчислимое (тёмное) множество.

А Вам почему кажется неверным, что корень здесь не **Т-, а тьм-**?

Корень **Т-** вычленяется в указательном местоимении то, та,те, того, тому и т.д., но это совсем другой корень, он указывает на отдалённый предмет. Тьма здесь ни при чём.

Comment: пятьма, десятьма и т.п. тоже этимологическое наречие? думаю все они стали наречиями уже в русском языке (по аналогии со всё тем же "отовсюду")  по причине "урезания" старославянской падежной системы под русский язык.

Comment: Исхожу из того, что тьма ранее была числительным, а одна из падежных форм числительного образовывалась путем добавления -(ь)ма (современное русское -(ь)мя: двумя, тремя, четырьмя).

Comment: Не числительным, а счётным словом -существительным, и сами числительные были существительными (1,2,5..) и прилагательными (3,4). https://studopedia.ru/11_145012_istoriya-imeni-chislitelnogo.html ма- окончание творит. падежа, а тьма  - им. п.